# Reading a text file into an array does nothing when Submit is clicked

Tags: vb.net

I need this program to take the countries.txt file and read it into the country.countryarray when the program loads. Then the user needs to be able to enter a country name in the nmtext.text field and click submit and the country abbreviation should be pulled from the array and displayed in the abbrevtext.text field and complete the same action if the user searches an abbreviation from the abbrevtext.text field then it needs to display the country name in the nmtext.text field.

The countries.txt file has 250 countries and has to be stored in the debug file for the project and the contents of the file look like this when viewed in notepad++ with a carriage return at the end of each line.

```
0.AC
1.Ascension Island
2.AD
3.Andorra
4.AE
5.United Arab Emirates
6.AF
7.Afghanistan
8.AG
9.Antigua and Barbuda
10.AI
```

Here is my code so far and it is not working it will pop up the form and let me enter a country name but it doesn't do anything when I hit submit.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
Public Class CountForm

'CREATES STRUCTURE AND ARRAY
Public Structure Countries
    Public CountryArray
    Public CountryString As String
End Structure

'CREATES OBJECT FOR STRUCTURE
Public Country As Countries

'CREATES STREAM READER
Private MyStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader

'CREATES FILESTRING VARIALE TO REFERENCE THE FILE PATH 
Public FileString As String      = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Basic\CountryFile\CountryFile\bin\Debug\Countries.Txt"

'CREATES TEXTFIELDPARSER AND REFERENCES FILESTRING TO CALL THE FILEPATH
Private TextFieldParser As New TextFieldParser(FileString)


Private Sub CountForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try
        Country.CountryArray = File.ReadAllText(FileString) '// gets all the text in the file'

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim ResponseDialogResult As String
        ' File missing.
        ResponseDialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Something Went Wrong",
        "Debuging Purposes", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Question)

        If ResponseDialogResult = DialogResult.Yes Then


        End If
        If ResponseDialogResult = DialogResult.No Then
            ' Exit the program.
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Submit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Submit.Click
    Try

        TextFieldParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
        TextFieldParser.SetDelimiters(Environment.NewLine)

        Do Until MyStreamReader.Peek = -1
            If NmText.Text.ToUpper.Contains(Country.CountryArray.ToUpper()) Then
                AbbrevText.Text = Country.CountryArray.ToUpper - 1
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Name or Abbreviation Was Not Found", "Error",     MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            End If

        Loop
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub Clear_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Clear.Click
    NmText.Text = ""
    AbbrevText.Text = ""
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Get rid of that empty try/catch and maybe you'll see what exception is occurring. Never hide exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Did that and it is flagging a few things now. Sorry code is sloppy I have been messing with it for hours now and have tried several different things to get it working.  Telling me that the environment.newline isn't an acceptable delimiter. I did it like that because in the text file there is a cr at the end of each line. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @user2796618   instead of Environment.Newline, try using one of the following: `vbcrlf`, `vbcr`, or `vblf`. You may be getting the error because the Enivironment is dependent on the OS settings of the machine the code is being executed on.

Comment: There are many issues with the code. I can't work out the purpose of `MyStreamReader`, but it is not initialized in the code you provided (`Private MyStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader` does not create an instance).  Also, all you ever do with it is `Peek`, which to me looks like it will just result in an infinite loop in `Submit_Click`.  Also, where you do read the file in `CountForm_Load`, `Country.CountryArray` is not an array.  Perhaps a good place to start would be to add `Option Strict On` and `Option Explicit On` at the top of the file to point out some basic errors.

Answer (score 0):

The StreamReader/TextFieldParser approach seems really complicated. Maybe this works for you:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private countryDict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim lineArray = IO.File.ReadAllLines("countries.txt")

        'this will cause trouble if there is a NewLine at the end of the file
        'In this case just remove the last new line.
        For index = 0 To lineArray.Length - 2 Step 2
            countryDict.Add(lineArray(index), lineArray(index + 1))
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Submit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Submit.Click
        If countryDict.ContainsKey(NmText.Text.ToUpper()) Then
            AbbrevText.Text = countryDict(NmText.Text.ToUpper())
        Else
            MsgBox("Name or Abbreviation Was Not Found")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I have to use the StreamReader to meet the requirements and I agree it is a pain. Sorry Thanks for comment.

Comment: Do you have to use the TextFieldParser?